# Why is mybatis reporting this error in this concurrent scenario, the springboot integrated sqlsessiontemplate is not thread safe?

Tags: spring-boot, thread-safety, mybatis

** fisrt. My project is about the list of articles recommended,every article have there own rule,so i use AsyncTaskExecutor this tool class to concurrent query different articles, and now,some rules is special,So I split them into different rules into two parts. next is my code:
i use springboot + mybatis to do**

```
@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor dataTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(16);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("data_task_executor-");
    return executor;
}
```

**here i initialization AsyncTaskExecutor class for ready
Next is the partial code of the concurrent query.**

```
    // here i get different rule list

    List<Rule> ruleList = JSON.parseArray(scene.getRules(), Rule.class);
    Iterator<Rule> ruleIterator = ruleList.iterator();
    CountDownLatch latch1 = new CountDownLatch(ruleList.size());
    while (ruleIterator.hasNext()) {
       Rule ruleNext = ruleIterator.next();
       // unAsyncScenes is a array,this rule query in here
       if (Arrays.binarySearch(unAsyncScenes, ruleNext.getSource()) >= 0) { 
          dataTaskExecutor.execute(() -> {
              try {
                  searchIDSByRule(idWithRtsMap, articleReferralList, sceneId, feedSum, userId, isNewUserByHistory, discussHistoryList, discussList, graphHistorys, ruleNext);
                   //Record browsing history
                   graphHistorys.addAll(idWithRtsMap.keySet());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  log.warn("子规则查图失败", e);
              } finally {
                  latch1.countDown();
              }

          });
          //Query deleted
          ruleIterator.remove();
      } else {
          latch1.countDown();
      }

    }
    try {
        latch1.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("多线等待异常:", e);
    }
    //deal with Duplicate article
    Set<Long> articleSet = new HashSet();
    articleReferralList.forEach(article -> articleSet.add(article));
    if (articleReferralList.size() != articleSet.size()) {
        log.warn("出现了重复的文章");
        articleReferralList.clear();
        articleReferralList.addAll(articleSet);
    }       
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(ruleList.size());   
    for (Rule rule : ruleList) {
        // second concurrent query(query for other article)
        dataTaskExecutor.execute(() -> {
            try { *****// here hava error！！！！！！！！！！！！***** 
                searchIDSByRule(idWithRtsMap, articleReferralList, sceneId, feedSum, userId, isNewUserByHistory, discussHistoryList, discussList, graphHistorys, rule);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.warn("子规则查图失败", e);
            } finally {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
    }
    try {
        latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         log.error("多线等待异常:", e);
    }
```

this is all query code, but went i run this code, it sometimes gives an error like this:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: \
### Error querying database. Cause: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\
### Cause: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:77) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!\/:1.3.1]\
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!\/:1.3.1]\
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:230) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!\/:1.3.1]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:137) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:75) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.searchBySigAndExample(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\
    at com.coffee.ref.service.impl.ReferralServiceImpl.searchIDSByRule(ReferralServiceImpl.java:842) ~[classes!\/:0.0.1]\
    at com.coffee.ref.service.impl.ReferralServiceImpl.lambda$findArticleIDSByRule$7(ReferralServiceImpl.java:625) ~[classes!\/:0.0.1]\
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]\
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]\
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]\
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: \
### Error querying database. Cause: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\
### Cause: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:150) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]\
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]\
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!\/:1.3.1]\
    ... 11 more\
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909) ~[?:1.8.0_212]\
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859) ~[?:1.8.0_212]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ForEachSqlNode.apply(ForEachSqlNode.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:33) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:35) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:33) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:41) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:292) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor.intercept(PageInterceptor.java:83) ~[pagehelper-5.1.2.jar!\/:?]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy188.query(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]\
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]\
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]\
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar!\/:1.3.1]\
    ... 11 more\"}"]
```

The place where the error was reported is marked above.I don't understand why, mybatis should be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5jTm.png)

The official documentation says it is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlSessionTemplate` itself is thread safe. The problem is in your code.

The exception shows that error happens in the `foreach` element. Note this piece of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909) ~[?:1.8.0_212]\
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859) ~[?:1.8.0_212]\
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ForEachSqlNode.apply(ForEachSqlNode.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar!\/:3.4.5]\
```

So what happens here? In the mapper you build SQL dynamically by iterating over some collection. This collection is modified concurrently by another thread. The iterator over the collection has built-in check that collection is not modified and this check indicates you that there is a problem.

In order to fix this you need to synchronize access to the collection that is used in multiple threads so that when you use the collection to query some data based on it this happens atomically and no modification can happen in the middle of the query generation.

One possible reason of this is that the result of this `await` is not analyzed:

```
latch1.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If the processing takes more than 10 seconds the second part starts executing while the data that query is based on is still being modified. This can happen as the amount of work to do depends on the data.

You need to check the result of this `await` and do not continue processing until all tasks in the first part of the procedure are finished.

Comment: First of all, I am very grateful for your answer, but I still have a question. At the beginning, in the first part of the code, I did not use the multi-threaded form to query, but a single-threaded loop query. At this time, the second part of the multi-threading The query is no problem, but when I transform the first part into a multi-threaded query, the second part starts to report an error.

Comment: 而且
try {
                latch1.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("多线等待异常:", e);
            }
This part of the code should be separated from the two concurrent, I do not understand why the logic of the first part is modified, which will affect the dynamic sql formation of the second part.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. At the beginning, when I set await time to 2S, I did report this error. I just didn't expect to have more than 10s. But in theory, it is only possible for this reason. Thank you very much for your Solution